# Cannot install requests on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pip, python-requests

When I issue `pip3 install requests` on my terminal cmd line I got back:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: There
>   was a problem confi rming the ssl certificate: [SSL:
>   TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol versi on
>   (_ssl.c:661) - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement requests (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for requests

How can I install requests module?

Comment: Which version of Python is this? Run `python3 --version` to see.

Comment: python 3.6.4 ;)